# Get event information in triggers in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a trigger in Oracle that gets fired on insert or update on a particular table. Inside the trigger, I want to determine the event that fired the trigger (whether insert or update?). How do I determine the event information in PL SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `INSERTING` and `UPDATING` keywords

```
IF INSERTING
THEN
  <<do something>>
END IF;

IF UPDATING
THEN
  <<do something else>>
END IF;
```